# Keeping two cross-communicating asio io_service objects busy

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am using boost:asio with multiple io_services to keep different forms of blocking I/O separate. E.g. I have one io_service for blocking file I/O, and another for long-running CPU-bound tasks (and this could be extended to a third for blocking network I/O, etc.) Generally speaking I want to ensure that one form of blocking I/O cannot starve the others.

The problem I am having is that since tasks running in one io_service can post events to other io_service (e.g. a CPU-bound task may need to start a file I/O operation, or a completed file I/O operation may invoke a CPU-bound callback), I don't know how to keep both io_services running until they are both out of events.

Normally with a single I/O service, you do something like:

```
 shared_ptr<asio::io_service> io_service (new asio::io_service);
 shared_ptr<asio::io_service::work> work (
   new asio::io_service::work(*io_service));

 // Create worker thread(s) that call io_service->run()

 io_service->post(/* some event */);

 work.reset();

 // Join worker thread(s)
```

However if I simply do this for both io_services, the one into which I did not post an initial event finishes immediately. And even if I post initial events to both, if the initial event on io_service B finishes before the task on io_service A posts a new event to B, io_service B will finish prematurely.

How can I keep io_service B running while io_service A is still processing events (because one of the queued events in service A might post a new event to B), and vice-versa, while still ensuring that both io_services exit their run() methods if they are ever both out of events at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out a way to do this, so documenting it for the record in case anyone else finds this question in a search:

- Create each N cross-communicating io_services, create a work object for each of them, and then start their worker threads.
- Create a "master" io_service object which will not run any worker threads.
- Do not allow posting events directly to the services. Instead, create accessor functions to the io_services which will:

  1. Create a work object on the master thread.
  2. Wrap the callback in a function that runs the real callback, then deletes the work.
  3. Post this wrapped callback instead.
- In the main flow of execution, once all of the N io_services have started and you have posted work to at least one of them, call run() on the master io_service.
- When the master io_service's run() method returns, delete all of the initial work on the N cross-communicating io_services, and join all worker threads.

Having the master io_service's thread own work on each of the other io_services ensures that they will not terminate until the master io_service runs out of work. Having each of the other io_services own work on the master io_service for every posted callback ensure that the master io_service will not run out of work until every one of the other io_services no longer has any posted callbacks left to process.

An example (could be enapsulated in a class):

```
shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> master_io_service;

void RunWorker(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_service) {
  io_service->run();
}

void RunCallbackAndDeleteWork(boost::function<void()> callback,
                              boost::asio::io_service::work* work) {
  callback();
  delete work;
}

// All new posted callbacks must come through here, rather than being posted
// directly to the io_service object.
void PostToService(boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_service,
                   boost::function<void()> callback) {
  io_service->post(boost::bind(
      &RunCallbackAndDeleteWork, callback,
      new boost::asio::io_service::work(*master_io_service)));
}

int main() {
  vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> > io_services;
  vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work> > initial_work;
  boost::thread_pool worker_threads;

  master_io_service.reset(new boost::asio::io_service);

  const int kNumServices = X;
  const int kNumWorkersPerService = Y;
  for (int i = 0; i < kNumServices; ++i) {
    shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service> io_service(new boost::asio::io_service);
    io_services.push_back(io_service);
    initial_work.push_back(new boost::asio::io_service::work(*io_service));

    for (int j = 0; j < kNumWorkersPerService; ++j) {
      worker_threads.create_thread(boost::bind(&RunWorker, io_service));
    }
  }

  // Use PostToService to start initial task(s) on at least one of the services

  master_io_service->run();

  // At this point, there is no real work left in the services, only the work
  // objects in the initial_work vector.
  initial_work.clear();
  worker_threads.join_all();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [HTTP server example 2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server2/io_service_pool.cpp) does something similar that you may find useful. It uses the concept of an `io_service` pool that retains `vector`s of `shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service>` and a `shared_ptr<boost::asio::io_service::work>` for each `io_service`. It uses a thread pool to run each service.

The example uses a round-robin scheduling for doling out work to the I/O services, I don't think that will apply in your case since you have specific tasks for `io_service` A and `io_service` B.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about io_service::work.  I always scheduled a timer at infinity.  +1

Comment: Good example, but not quite what I needed, because in that example the worker threads for one service never post events to one of the other services.